# Finding a better way to implement navigation bar which has subcategories

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I'm building a navigation bar. The link below is what I just have completed so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/dsdzyp23/2/

```html
<div class="navbar-01">
  <div class="navbar-01-container">
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="logo-center">
        <img style="width: 240px;" src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg">
      </div>
      <button class="nav-toggle-btn">
     <img style="width: 50px;" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ui-icon-part-2/128/navigation-512.png">
    </button>
      <ul class="nav-categories">
        <li><a href="#runway" data-sub-nav="runway">RUNWAY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#women" data-sub-nav="women">WOMEN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#men" data-sub-nav="men">MEN</a></li>
        <li><a href="#children" data-sub-nav="children">CHILDREN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="runway" class="navbar-sub">
    <div class="main-container">
      <div class="nav-sub-list">
        <ul class="nav-sub-categories">
          <a href="#women">WOMEN</a>
          <li><a href="#Cruise-2018">Cruise 2018</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Fall-Winter-2017-Runway">Fall Winter 2017 Runway</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pre-Fall-2017">Pre-Fall 2017</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- 
     -->
        <ul class="nav-sub-categories">
          <a href="#men">MEN</a>
          <li><a href="#Cruise-2018">Cruise 2018</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Fall-Winter-2017-Runway">Fall Winter 2017 Runway</a></li>
          <li><a href="#Pre-Fall-2017">Pre-Fall 2017</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- 
      -->
        <ul class="nav-sub-categories">
          <a href="#unskilled-worker">UNSKILLED WORKER</a>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Cause my subcategories are not wrapped with anchors, when my mouse leaves the anchor, the subcategories div closes, therefore I cannot reach to the content which are wrapped in the subcategories div.
I' am wondering if wrapping subcategories with anchor is the best way to implement a navigation bar? (Considering to responsive web design, it seems like wrapping together is the most easiest way to implement?)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the standard way to make a menu. It's also dependent on requirements.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-list {
  text-align: center;
}
.nav-list-item {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.nav-list-item:hover .subnav-list {
  display: block;
}

.subnav-list {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 1</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 2</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 3</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 4</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 5</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 6</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 7</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 8</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 9</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-list-item">
      <a href="" class="subnav-link">Nav 10</a>
      <ul class="subnav-list">
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 1</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 2</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 3</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 4</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 5</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 6</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 7</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 8</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 9</a></li>
        <li class="subnav-list-item"><a href="">Sub Nav 10</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```